# Can't position child layout in root layout Kivy

Tags: python, layout, kivy

I am quite new to kivy and graphical programming in general. I am trying to position a child layout-object inside a root layout in kivy. My child layout contains two buttons, and I want it positioned at the top of my screen.

```
class Homescreen(FloatLayout):

def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super(Homescreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    button_holder = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal", 
                              spacing=10, 
                              padding=[20,10], 
                              pos=(0,0))

    calendar_button = Button(text="Calendar", 
                             size=(200,100), 
                             size_hint=(None,None))

    add_activity_button = Button(text="Add activity", 
                                 size=(200,100), 
                                 size_hint=(None,None))

    button_holder.add_widget(add_activity_button)
    button_holder.add_widget(calendar_button)
    self.add_widget(button_holder)
```

This is the code in which I create my root (and child) layout. I however recieve a window like this:
[image: Agenda app]

Kivy's documentation wasn't of much help, any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

The BoxLayout is at the bottom-left of the window because of `pos=(0,0)`.

## Solution

Replace `pos` with [pos_hint](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint) e.g. `pos_hint={'x': 0.23, 'y': 0.8}`

[Widget class » pos_hint](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint)

```
pos_hint
```

Position hint. This property allows you to set the position of the widget inside its parent layout, in percent (similar to size_hint).

For example, if you want to set the top of the widget to be at 90% height of its parent layout, you can write:

```
widget = Widget(pos_hint={'top': 0.9})
```

The keys ‘x’, ‘right’ and ‘center_x’ will use the parent width. The keys ‘y’, ‘top’ and ‘center_y’ will use the parent height.

See [Float Layout](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.floatlayout.html) for further reference.

**Note**

`pos_hint` is not used by all layouts. Check the documentation of the layout in question to see if it supports pos_hint.

`pos_hint` is an ObjectProperty containing a dict.

## Output

[image: Img01]